# How to parse text from <div class="name"> with Jsoup?

Tags: android, parsing, html, jsoup

I have div with name "right-content". I need to get all text from `<h1>-<p>` which is in this `<div>.` How can I make it with Jsoup? Help me please.

```
 <div name="right-content">
    <h1>Kontakt</h1>
    <p><strong>SOME TEXT</strong></p><br/>
    <p>SOME TEXT</p>
    <p>SOME TEXT</p>
    ......
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select `Elements` based on specific attributes, using the syntax `el[attr]` just as the [Jsoup cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) suggests.

In your case, you'd use `doc.select("div[name=right-content]")` to select that specific `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Jsoup For Html Parsing its a best solution for your problem, Just download Jsoup.jar and import it to your project as external jars and just follow the following code.
use getElementByTag() method for that

Forexample

```
String result="";
Document doc=Jsoup.connect(YourUrl).get();
Element nodeBlogStats = document.getElementByTag("div");
for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element row : nodeBlogStats.select("h1")) {
        for (org.jsoup.nodes.Elements column : row.select("p")) {
            result += column.text();
        }
}
Toast.makeText(context,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//this will just show the result in Toast message
```

Hope this will help you...